# DCA BOT --- If the problem --- Multiple reception problem

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

When one of the stages is not fulfilled, the other stages become ineffective, but I want it to continue.

When it continues, it executes the order of the previous unfulfilled stage.

How can i prevent this

```
> >  if long66 
>     strategy.entry('Base order', strategy.long, qty=100/close, when=long55 and strategy.opentrades == 0,
>      comment='BO' + str.tostring(current_so) + str.tostring(100))
>     current_so := current_so +  1 else 
>     current_so := current_so + 1
> 
> if  long66 <= kademe1 and long66 > kademe2
>     strategy.entry('Long1' , strategy.long, qty=200/close,
>      when=(strategy.opentrades <= current_so) and strategy.position_size > 0 and not(strategy.opentrades ==1), 
>      comment='SO' + str.tostring(current_so) + ' - ' + (str.tostring(100))  )
>     current_so := current_so + 1
> 
> else    
>     current_so := current_so + 1
>     
>      if   long66 < kademe2 and  long66 > kademe3
>     strategy.entry("Long2" , strategy.long, qty=200/close,
>      when=(strategy.opentrades <= current_so) and strategy.position_size > 0 and not(strategy.opentrades == 2), 
>      comment='SO' + str.tostring(current_so) + ' - ' + (str.tostring(200)) )
>     current_so := current_so + 1   else 
>     current_so := current_so + 1
> 
> 
> if  long66 < kademe3 and long66 > kademe4
>     strategy.entry('long3' + "i_s", strategy.long, qty=200/close,
>      when=(strategy.opentrades <= current_so) and strategy.position_size > 0 and not(strategy.opentrades == 3 ), 
>      comment='SO' + str.tostring(current_so) + ' - ' + (str.tostring(300))  )
>     current_so := current_so + 1     else
>     current_so := current_so + 1
>     
> 
> 
> if  long66 < kademe4 and long66 > kademe5
>     strategy.entry('Long4' , strategy.long, qty=200/close,
>      when=(strategy.opentrades <= current_so) and strategy.position_size > 0 and not(strategy.opentrades == 4), 
>      comment='SO' + str.tostring(current_so) + ' - ' + (str.tostring(400))  )
>     current_so := current_so + 1        else
>     current_so := current_so + 1 
> 
> 
> if  long66 <= kademe5 and long66 > kademe6
>     strategy.entry("long5", strategy.long, qty=200/close,
>      when=(strategy.opentrades <= current_so) and strategy.position_size > 0 and not(strategy.opentrades == 5), 
>      comment='SO' + str.tostring(current_so) + ' - ' + (str.tostring(500)) )
>     current_so := current_so + 1       else 
>     current_so := current_so + 1
> 
> 
> 
> if  long66 <= kademe6
>     strategy.entry("long6", strategy.long, qty=200/close,
>      when=(strategy.opentrades <= current_so) and strategy.position_size > 0 and not(strategy.opentrades == 6), 
>      comment='SO' + str.tostring(current_so) + ' - ' + (str.tostring(600)) )
>     current_so := 6
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wUHi.png)

Comment: You should rephrase your question to make people better understand what you would like to achieve (like "I have a grid bot that I wanted to behave like this <>. Here's the code. What I experience is this <>")

Comment: Did you see the picture I attached?

Comment: Yes I saw it, didn't help much. For instance what does "continue" mean in your case?

Comment: I want to block consecutive purchases,
let him buy one when his condition is right

Comment: Based on your picture it looks the one with the comment `SO03` was executed multiple times. I haven't seen the code that sets the `kademe` variables, maybe you are overwriting their value improperly.